# Django form errors are not showing up

Tags: python, django

I have looked all over stackoverflow and the Internet about this so I will just show my code.

*views.py*

```
def UserSell(request,username):

theuser=User.objects.get(username=username)
thegigform=GigForm()
#if the user is submitting a form
if request.method=='POST':
    #bind form with form inputs and image
    gigform=GigForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if gigform.is_valid():
        gigform.title=gigform.cleaned_data['title']
        gigform.description=gigform.cleaned_data['description']
        gigform.more_info=gigform.cleaned_data['more_info']
        gigform.time_for_completion=gigform.cleaned_data['time_for_completion']
        gigform.gig_image=gigform.cleaned_data['gig_image']
        finalgigform=gigform.save(commit=False)
        finalgigform.from_user=theuser
        finalgigform.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('done')
thegigform=GigForm()
context=RequestContext(request)
return render_to_response('sell.html',{'theuser':theuser,'thegigform':thegigform},context_instance=context)
```

*template*

```
<form action="{% url sell user.username %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<fieldset>
    <legend><h2>Sell A Gig</h2></legend>
    {% for f in thegigform %}
    <div class="formWrapper">
        {{f.errors}}
        {{f.label_tag}}: {{f}}
        {{f.help_text}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Sell Now!" />
```

This code seems to follow normal django form protocol so please tell me why my django template doesnt show the errors. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing an else block.

if gigform.valid() returns false, you are overwriting the variable "thegigform".  Try restructuring your code like this:

```
if request.method=='POST':
    #bind form with form inputs and image
    thegigform=GigForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if thegigform.is_valid():
        thegigform.title=gigform.cleaned_data['title']
        thegigform.description=gigform.cleaned_data['description']
        thegigform.more_info=gigform.cleaned_data['more_info']
        thegigform.time_for_completion=gigform.cleaned_data['time_for_completion']
        thegigform.gig_image=gigform.cleaned_data['gig_image']
        finalgigform=gigform.save(commit=False)
        finalgigform.from_user=theuser
        finalgigform.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('done')
else:
    thegigform=GigForm()
context=RequestContext(request)
return render_to_response('sell.html',{'theuser':theuser,'thegigform':thegigform},context_instance=context)
```

Comment: that is what i had in my code before but was told to change that so i put else back in to catch if request is get. Problem not solved

Comment: Do you see why in your posted code you would never see the errors?  if gigform.is_valid() returns False, then you are going down the same code path as request.method != 'POST'.  That is, you are creating a new GigForm object.  To see the errors rendered you need to set 'thegigform' in your context to the same object which is causing gigform.is_valid() to return False.

Comment: so the context will be gigform? Im sorry im having trouble doing this can you show me what the code should look like. thegigform=gigform....{'thegigform':thegigform} like that?

Comment: sorry i fixed the problem i was renaming GigForm "thegigform" instead of using gigform like i used in the post. Thanks for help though